# on captcha-code and best-practices implementation

Tags: php, implementation, captcha

i had a discussion with a friend about using captcha-code and it's implementation, here is what come out from the discussion:

- it is usefull in preventing brute-force login attemps;
- it can be circumvented;
- it is not user-friendly;
- a good approach of it, is hard to implement;

i want to know from you geeks what about best-practices of  implementing captcha-code <del>in a CMS system</del>.

as always, thank's to all for the time.

Comment: http://www.google.com/recaptcha is the most popular captcha and is(was?) also used by big sites like twitter when I registered.

Comment: @Alfred: too easy as answer, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: That's why I made it a comment this time ;). But it is the right answer ;)?

Comment: @Alfred: i know my friend, you are always welcome. ;-)

Comment: Also the best approach is probably authentication via openID(google). let the user only once have to fill-in a captcha when registering account.

Answer (score 1):

For CodeIgniter we created a recaptcha library and a recaptcha view so adding it to our sites is very simple. Google's recaptcha implementation is very easy to integrate.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: thank's dude, but i know how to google! :-)  i'm not searching a copy/past solution but a good pattern that rely on the points above. tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, I'd recommend excluding 0 and o, and 1 and l, as they can look like eachother a lot.
Sometimes I too, or 8 and B